# Generating a random binary matrix with a constraint

Tags: matlab

We are using MATLAB and we would like to generate a binary matrix, say `x(i,j,k)`, where for every `i`, this condition is satisfied `sum_{j} \ sum_{k} x_{ijk} = 1`. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate random subscripts for `j` and `k` and use [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to convert subscripts to indexes.

```
x = false(ni, nj, nk);  
subi = 1:ni;
subj = randi(nj, 1, ni);
subk = randi(nk, 1, ni);
ind = sub2ind([ni, nj, nk], subi, subj, subk);
x(ind) = true;
```

To confirm the constraint you can use:

```
all(sum(sum(x, 3), 2) == 1)
```